# Firebase Analytics even show up in log but not on firebase console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am trying to integrate Firebase RemoteConfig and Analytics with my Android application. Remote configuration part is working but Analytics part is not working. Here is my `build.gradle`

```
   // Firebase configuration
   compile group:'com.google.firebase', name:'firebase-core', version: '9.4.0'
   compile group:'com.google.firebase', name:'firebase-config', version: '9.4.0'

   // Firebase analytics
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.4.0'
```

Here is my Activity code.

```
 FirebaseAnalytics firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
      firebaseAnalytics.setUserId("5107611364");
      firebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty("custom_user_property", "custom_user_proerty_value");

      Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
      bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "SomeID");
      bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "SomeIDName");
      bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "IdType");
      firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
```

I am trying to publish customer property as well as the event but both of them are not working. I have enabled adb logging and I can see that custom event and property are published. These do not appear on the Firebase Analytics console even after 24hrs. I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Do you add that user property in dashboard?

Comment: @Dentor I did add that property to the dashboard. But it still doesn't show up in stats.

Comment: Just a comment on your dependencies.  I doubt this is causing the problem.  Firebase Analytics is in the `firebase-core` library.  You don't need to include `play-services-analytics`. Ref [Getting Started Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start/)

Comment: I believe Getting-started documented is not updated correctly. In the document they mention that they are using 9.2.1 but in sample app which is present on [github](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/analytics/app/build.gradle#L29-L36) they are using 9.4.0 and they have not included the core library. I believe they have removed the core library and put the classes in analytics library.

Comment: Yes, I see your point and wasn't aware of that.  Still, you are including `play-services-analytics`.  Did you intend to include `firebase-analytics` as is done in the sample app?

Comment: @qbix My bad, I didn't realized that you are pointing to `play-services-analytics`. I have changed it to `firebase-analytics`. I am testing now hopefully it will appear after sometime. I will post the update here after few hours.

Comment: @qbix I didn't see any changes in the analytics log. Logs lines are looking exactly the same as it was before.

Comment: Do you have a recent version of Google Play Services installed on your device?  I think others have seen similar problems when GPS was not installed or was an old version.

Comment: Sometimes it takes a couple of hours for the events to be registered in the firebase console.

Comment: @qbix I have the latest version of google play but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @dazza5000 it already been more than 12 hours and I have not seen that event on the Firebase console.

Comment: Another guess: Maybe there is something wrong with your `google-services.json` file.  In the `adb` log output, there are FA-SVC messages output when a bundle of event data is uploaded.  The bundle params include `gmp_app_id`, `app_id`, and `firebase_instance_id`. Do the values of those params look right?

Comment: The [Google Services Gradle Plugin documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin) is helpful for understanding the contents and processing of `google-services.json`.

Answer (score 7):

@Rakesh - you are looking in the wrong location.  You are supplying customID feilds, in your example you are supplying **CONTENT_TYPE : IdType**. You don't need a minimum of 10 users to see the data...if you only have 1 user that data will appear within 24 hours of that user using your app.

I will say this, initially finding your own custom IDs is not very straight forward...it took me a while to find it too.

The place to find that custom reported info is: **Anaylytics - Events** - once on this page, click on the actual **CONTENT_TYPE** you are wishing to track, in your example above, it would be **idType**
[image: Analytics -> Events]

Then on the **Content** graph you will see your customIDs *(ie: someID)*...click on **someID**. In my case (and in my screenshots) my equivelant **someIDs** are "*field, button & select*"
[image: Events -> CONTENT_TYPE]

and then you will see all the data related to the values *(someIDName)* you passed into **someID**.
[image: CONTENT_TYPE -> customIDs]

Now, if **idType** is not appearing for you then that may because Firebase isn't allowing you to create your own **CONTENT_TYPE**, I am not certain if you can do that as I have not tried...and in that case you would need to use a predefined **CONTENT_TYPE**.  I am not using a custom **idType**, I am using **CONTENT_TYPE : select_content**.